# bootstrap3 Datetimepicker set TimePicker Value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ to generate a Time Picker Using the following code:

```
console.log(now);
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: true,
        format: 'HH:mm',
        defaultDate: now
    });

});
```

My **now** Value is calculated like this:

```
var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'T'+ '@ViewBag.End'+'.000';
```

The **ViewBag.End** provides me a time string from my SQL Server. The Value of **now** according to my console is:

- 2016-03-26T15:00:00.000

But when I run the page I get the following:
[image: Time End according to Application]
It displays as 20:00. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. By changing my date picker declaration to include the following:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: true,
        format: 'HH:mm'
    });
    $("#datetimepicker3").find("input").val('@ViewBag.End'); //This sets the value correctly
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is pulling filling HH with the first two digits. 20 in this case, and MM with the first two digits after a colon 00 in this case. You will need to pass only the hour and minutes instead of now to defaultDate if you only want to display HH:MM

Comment: When I and just past the time string I get from server, I get this error: *TypeError: defaultDate() Could not parse date parameter: 15:00:00*